# RN Expo. FETCH_ERROR when uploading image to the server

Tags: react-native, file-upload, expo, rtk-query

When uploading image to the server via RTK query
`{"error": "TypeError: Network request failed", "status": "FETCH_ERROR"}`

**Mutation:**

```js
updateMasterData: builder.mutation({
  query: (data) => ({
    url: urls.updateMasterData,
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
  }),
}),
```

**FormData:**

```js
const data = new FormData();
data.append("name", name);
data.append("phone_number_2", phoneNumber2);
data.append("region_id", selectedRegion.id);
data.append("address", address);
data.append("passport_num", formattedpassportNumber);
data.append("lang", lang);
data.append("occupations", selectedOccupations.map((occ) => occ.id).join(","));
data.append("passport_image", {
  uri: imageUri,
  type: mime.getType(imageUri),
  name: imageUri.split("/").pop(),
});
```

In iOS working fine. In Android 13 some times giving this error. But Android 11 stuck in status pending and after a while giving abore error. Tried sending via base64. But no luck the same issue